# Fontawesome is installed - icons do not appear

Tags: font-awesome

After installing fontawesome, I copied the icon I wanted to appear in my word document from http://fontawesome.io/icons/

When I paste the icon in my word document, it does not appear. I tried various icons. Various signs appear, from vertical stripes to greek letters, yet no icons.  

Comment: This is not a programming question. Highlight the various incorrect icons in your document and change the font to Font Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to copy and paste an icon from Font Awesome after installing the font you need to do it from this page.

[Font Awesome Cheat Sheet](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/)